# Perl Loop add to Hash

Tags: perl, hash

I am trying to loop over all the values in my config file and put the data into an array. I just need to get the block as the key and then the setting name as the value.

```
#Config File looks like this

[Actions]
action=0
actionCR=1
actionHighlight=1

[Hotkeys]
key=38
keyCR=32
keyHighlight=39

[Settings]
chbAcronym=1
chbCompleted=0

# End Config




my %settingsTemplate;
my $settingsTemplate;

# Loop over each section in the template
foreach my $section (keys %{$cfg}) {

    # Loop over all the setting titles
    foreach my $parameter (keys %{$cfg->{$section}}) {

        # Push setting titles to an array
        $settingsTemplate->{$section} = $parameter;

    }
}

print Dumper($settingsTemplate);

$VAR1 = {
      'Hotkeys' => 'key',
      'Actions' => 'actionCR',
      'Settings' => 'chbAcronym'
    };
```

This is how it prints the array which isnt what i need.

This is the desired output (not sure if my formatting is correct but hopefully you can understand it.

```
$VAR1 = {
      'Hotkeys',
             => 'key',
             => 'keyCR',
             => 'keyHighlight',
      'Actions',
             => 'action',
             => 'actionCR',
             => 'actionHighlight',
      'Settings',
             => 'chbAcronym',
             => 'chbCompleted'
    };
```

Comment: Why not use JSON, YAML or http://search.cpan.org/~drtech/Config-Merge-1.01/lib/Config/Merge.pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, use a hash of arrays and push.

Note that you will not get the keys in the order they were in the file; I would recommend changing:

```
foreach my $parameter (keys %{$cfg->{$section}}) {
```

to

```
foreach my $parameter (sort keys %{$cfg->{$section}}) {
```

so they have a consistent order, not one that varies.

Though the inner for loop is not actually needed; you can simply do:

```
# Loop over each section in the template
foreach my $section (keys %{$cfg}) {
    # Put setting titles into an array
    $settingsTemplate->{$section} = [ sort keys %{$cfg->{$section}} ];
}
```

or even more tersely:

```
my $settingsTemplate = { map { $_, [ sort keys %{$cfg->{$_}} ] } keys %$cfg };
```

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
push @{$settingsTemplate->{$section}}, $parameter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code performs an assignment instead of a push. Hashes in Perl only hold one value by default. You want a hash of arrays.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-ARRAYS

```
# Loop over each section in the template
foreach my $section (keys %{$cfg}) {

    # Loop over all the setting titles
    foreach my $parameter (keys %{$cfg->{$section}}) {

        # Push setting titles to an array
        push @{$settingsTemplate->{$section}}, $parameter;

    }
}
```